# Why does the main page settings from code not work in Maui?

Tags: c#, maui

I have been trying for weeks now to get around this issue which is through my `LoginViewModel` I want to navigate to the tabs page that has 4 bottom tab pages. I want to set mainpage to Appshell after successful login but nothing is happening.

Could this be a problem with MAUI or an emulator problem?

```
public async void loginSub()
{
    var response = await Login(Email, Password);

    if (response)
    {
        Application.Current.MainPage = new AppShell();
    }
    else
    {
        await Application.Current.MainPage.DisplayAlert("Oops", "Something went wrong", "Cancel");
    }
}
```

But for some reason, it is not navigating.

First I thought it was because it's executing from the view model, then I move it to code behind but still same thing. Please help me

Here this is my `App.xaml.cs`:

```
public App()
{
     InitializeComponent();
     
     var userEmaily = Preferences.Get("Emmaily", string.Empty);

     if (string.empty(userEmaily))
     {
         MainPage = new Views.Account.Cover();
     }
     else
     {
         MainPage = new AppShell();
     }
}
```

this is the login method

```
public static async Task<bool> Login(string username, string password)
{
    var login = new Login()
    {
        Username = username,
        Password = password
    };

    var httpClient = new HttpClient();
    var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(login);
    var content = new StringContent(json, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
    var response = await httpClient.PostAsync(SoccerMaui.Resources.Website.String1 + "Authorization/login", content);
    if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
    {
        var jsonResult = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<TokenT>(jsonResult);
        Preferences.Set("Emmaily", result.Email);
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        // Handle API error
        var problemDetailsz = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        await Application.Current.MainPage.DisplayAlert("Oops", problemDetailsz, "Cancel");
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [setting mainpage = Appshell in Viewmodel is not working in .Net MAUI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77586260/setting-mainpage-appshell-in-viewmodel-is-not-working-in-net-maui)

Comment: May I know whether your issue has been solved or not? If not, please share it in here. We can work together to figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

You can refer to this following code:

Create MAUI project and then add LoginPage and NewPage1 to root directory, also ViewModels folder within LoginViewModel:

[image]

LoginPage like this:

```xml
<ContentPage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="MauiApp5.LoginPage"
             Title="LoginPage"
             x:Name="this">
    <VerticalStackLayout>
        <Label
            Text="Welcome to .NET MAUI!"
            VerticalOptions="Center"
            HorizontalOptions="Center" />
        <Button Text="Login"  
                Command="{Binding LoginCommand}"
                CommandParameter="{Binding Source={Reference this}}"/>
    </VerticalStackLayout>
</ContentPage>
```

```cs
public partial class LoginPage : ContentPage
{
    public LoginPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.BindingContext = new LoginViewModel();
    }
}
```

LoginViewModel:

```cs
public class LoginViewModel
{
    public Command LoginCommand { get; }

    public LoginViewModel ()
    {
        LoginCommand = new Command<object> (OnLoginClicked);
    }

    private async void OnLoginClicked (object obj)
    {
        // Do some judgments whether user can jump the page
        //...
        var page = obj as ContentPage;
        await page.Navigation.PopToRootAsync ();
        Application.Current.MainPage = new AppShell ();
    }
}
```

App.xaml.cs:

```cs
public partial class App : Application
{
    public App ()
    {
        InitializeComponent ();

        MainPage = new NavigationPage (new LoginPage ());
        // MainPage = new AppShell();
    }
}
```

Here is the [effect](https://imgur.com/a/XcPfuFA).

**Update**

Just add your codes of LoginSub into OnLoginClicked:

```cs
private async void OnLoginClicked (object obj)
{

    var response = await Login (Email, Password);

    if (response)
    {
        var page = obj as ContentPage;
        await page.Navigation.PopToRootAsync ();
        Application.Current.MainPage = new AppShell ();
    }
    else
    {
        await Application.Current.MainPage.DisplayAlert ("Oops", "Something went wrong", "Cancel");
    }
}
```

Another solution:

Still create MAUI project and then add LoginPage and NewPage1 to root directory, also ViewModels folder within LoginViewModel.

AppShell.xaml:

```xml
<Shell
    x:Class="MauiApp6.AppShell"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MauiApp6"
    Shell.FlyoutBehavior="Disabled">


   <ShellContent Title="LoginPage" Route="LoginPage" ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate local:LoginPage}" Shell.TabBarIsVisible="False"/>
    
    <FlyoutItem >
        <ShellContent Title="Home" Route="MainPage" ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate local:MainPage}" />
        <ShellContent Title="NewPage1" Route="NewPage1" ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate local:NewPage1}" />
    </FlyoutItem>

</Shell>
```

LoginViewModel:

```cs
public class LoginViewModel
{
    public Command LoginCommand { get; }

    public LoginViewModel () { LoginCommand = new Command (OnLoginClicked); }

    private async void OnLoginClicked (object obj)
    {

        var response = await Login (Email, Password);

        if (response)
            {
                await Shell.Current.GoToAsync ($"//{nameof(MainPage)}");
            }
        else
            {
                await Application.Current.MainPage.DisplayAlert (
                    "Oops", "Something went wrong", "Cancel");
            }
    }
}
```

LoginPage.xaml:

```xml
<ContentPage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="MauiApp5.LoginPage"
             Title="LoginPage"
             x:Name="this">
    <VerticalStackLayout>
        <Label
            Text="Welcome to .NET MAUI!"
            VerticalOptions="Center"
            HorizontalOptions="Center" />
        <Button Text="Login"  
                Command="{Binding LoginCommand}"/>
    </VerticalStackLayout>
</ContentPage>
```

LoginPage.xaml.cs is the same as before, App.xaml.cs does not need to be changed. This solution is more concise and efficient than before, and here is the [effect](https://imgur.com/a/QVCcJac).

Comment: i have edited the question to include the login method and how i set the preferences.

Comment: I updated the answer, wish it can help you.

Comment: good day and sorry for the delay. this is what i'm talking about.. after succesful login i set the mainpage to be appshell and the appshell is a collection of bottom tabs just as in link  https://imgur.com/a/ia3FVn1   so i am not navigating to a singlepage but a collection of tabs but if i did not put the condition in app.xaml.cs it will navigate but its the condition i placed that is not making it navigate so that is my question. is there any workaround about it?

Comment: Sorry, I don't quite understand what you mean. Do you want this: open app, first page is LoginPage, after succesful login, app will jump to a collection of bottom tabs just as in link https://imgur.com/a/ia3FVn1 ? My second solution just means this.

Comment: yes... i added some conditions to check for some stored resources if present else it will go back to login..just like searching for tokens and if its not present it goes back to the login page for the user to login

Comment: So you mean you still need to go back to LoginPage? Just use `Shell.Current.GoToAsync($"//{nameof(LoginPage)}");` it can back to LoginPage.

Comment: Like this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/77682733/19902734.