# How do you replace a page with another in MAUI?

Tags: maui

I have a login page that appears first when my MAUI app runs. After login, I navigate to the dashboard page but my users can press the back button to go back to the login page.

Is there a way to close the login page after navigating to the dashboard page so the dashboard page becomes the root page?

In Android, I would go to the dashboard activity and execute "finish()" on the login page.

In summary, my question has multiple forms:

1. Is there a way to replace one page with another?
2. Is there a way to make a page become the new root page?
3. Is there a way to remove a root page from the navigation stack?

Comment: Those are three questions in one, you should focus on one per post only. However, you probably want to learn about navigation in MAUI in general: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/shows/dotnet-maui-for-beginners/navigating-between-pages-in-dotnet-maui-6-of-8-dotnet-maui-for-beginners

Comment: The 3 are actually the same question. 3 ways to solve the same problem. I'm just saying that whoever has an answer to one of the questions solves my problem.

Comment: Those are not congruent questions and there are also various possible answers as there are different ways to handle navigation in MAUI. You can use Shell, you can use a NavigationPage and push pages to the stack, you can manually set the `MainPage`... How much research have you done on this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can refer to this following code:

Create MAUI project and then add LoginPage and NewPage1 to root directory, also ViewModels folder within LoginViewModel:

[image]

LoginPage like this:

```xml
<ContentPage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="MauiApp5.LoginPage"
             Title="LoginPage">

    <VerticalStackLayout>
        <Label
            Text="Welcome to .NET MAUI!"
            VerticalOptions="Center"
            HorizontalOptions="Center" />
        <Button Text="Login"  
                Command="{Binding LoginCommand}"/>
    </VerticalStackLayout>
</ContentPage>
```

```cs
public partial class LoginPage : ContentPage
{
    public LoginPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.BindingContext = new LoginViewModel();
    }
}
```

LoginViewModel:

```cs
public class LoginViewModel
{
    public Command LoginCommand { get; }

    public LoginViewModel () { LoginCommand = new Command (OnLoginClicked); }

    private async void OnLoginClicked (object obj)
    {
         await Shell.Current.GoToAsync ($"//{nameof(MainPage)}");
    }
}
```

Add a button to MainPage for returning to LoginPage:

```xml
<ContentPage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="MauiApp5.MainPage">

   <ScrollView>
        <VerticalStackLayout
            Spacing="25"
            Padding="30,0"
            VerticalOptions="Center">

           .....

           <Button Text="LoginPage" Clicked="Button_Clicked"/>

       </VerticalStackLayout>
    </ScrollView>

</ContentPage>
```

```cs
public partial class MainPage: ContentPage 
{
  int count = 0;

  public MainPage() 
  {
    InitializeComponent();
  }
  
  ....
  
  private void Button_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e) 
  {
    Shell.Current.GoToAsync($"//{nameof(LoginPage)}");
  }
}
```

AppShell.xaml:

```xml
<Shell
    x:Class="MauiApp5.AppShell"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MauiApp5"
    Shell.FlyoutBehavior="Disabled">


   <ShellContent Title="LoginPage" Route="LoginPage" ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate local:LoginPage}" Shell.TabBarIsVisible="False"/>
    
    <FlyoutItem >
        <ShellContent Title="Home" Route="MainPage" ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate local:MainPage}" />
        <ShellContent Title="NewPage1" Route="NewPage1" ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate local:NewPage1}" />
    </FlyoutItem>

</Shell>
```

Here is the [effect](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VhS49.gif).

Comment: Thank you. This solved my problem "await Shell.Current.GoToAsync ($"//{nameof(MainPage)}");"