# Shell.Current.GoToAsync stopped working when upgrading project to .NET 8

Tags: android, maui

I have this XAML definition for the first page shown in an app:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<ContentPage
    x:Class="TimeApp.Views.LoadingPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:TimeApp.Views">
    <VerticalStackLayout VerticalOptions="Center" HorizontalOptions="Center">
        <ActivityIndicator Color="{StaticResource Primary}"
                               IsRunning="True" HeightRequest="50" WidthRequest="50"
                               IsVisible="True" />
        <Label Text="Cargando..." HorizontalOptions="Center" />
    </VerticalStackLayout>
</ContentPage>
```

In OnNavigatedTo override I have this:

```
protected override async void OnNavigatedTo(NavigatedToEventArgs args)
{
    await Shell.Current.GoToAsync($"///{nameof(LoginPage)}");
    base.OnNavigatedTo(args);
}
```

That did work but after .NET 8 upgrade, it stopped working. `LoginPage` is never shown and no error is thrown either.

How can I solve this? I am uing Android Emulator.

EDIT:

This is the AppShell.xaml file:

```
<FlyoutItem FlyoutDisplayOptions="AsMultipleItems">
        <ShellContent
                Title="Cargando"
                Shell.NavBarIsVisible="false"
                Shell.TabBarIsVisible="false"
                FlyoutItemIsVisible="False"
                ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate views:LoadingPage}"
                Route="LoadingPage" />
        <ShellContent Route="LoginPage"
                  Shell.NavBarIsVisible="false"
                  Shell.TabBarIsVisible="false"
                  FlyoutItemIsVisible="False"
                  ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate views:LoginPage}"/>
        <ShellContent Route="SettingsPage"
                  Shell.NavBarIsVisible="false"
                  Shell.TabBarIsVisible="false"
                  FlyoutItemIsVisible="False"
                  ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate views:SettingsPage}"/>
        <ShellContent
            Shell.NavBarIsVisible="true"
            Shell.TabBarIsVisible="false"
            Title="Visitas"
            ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate views:MainPage}"
            Route="MainPage">
            <ShellContent.Icon>
                <FontImageSource FontFamily="FontAwesomeSolid" Glyph="{x:Static helpers:FontAwesomeIcons.Briefcase}" Color="#0e8ebc" Size="50"/>
            </ShellContent.Icon>
        </ShellContent>
        <ShellContent
            Shell.NavBarIsVisible="true"
            Shell.TabBarIsVisible="false"
            Title="Configuración"
            ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate views:SettingsPage}"
            Route="MainPage">
            <ShellContent.Icon>
                <FontImageSource FontFamily="FontAwesomeSolid" Glyph="{x:Static helpers:FontAwesomeIcons.Settings}" Color="#0e8ebc" Size="50"/>
            </ShellContent.Icon>
        </ShellContent>
    </FlyoutItem>
    <MenuItem Text="Cerrar Sesión" Clicked="LogOut_Clicked">
        <MenuItem.IconImageSource>
            <FontImageSource FontFamily="FontAwesomeSolid" Glyph="{x:Static helpers:FontAwesomeIcons.SignOut}" Color="#0e8ebc" Size="50"/>
        </MenuItem.IconImageSource>
    </MenuItem>
    <Shell.FlyoutFooter>
        <controls:FooterControl />
    </Shell.FlyoutFooter>
```

This is the full code of LoadingPage.xaml code behind:

```
using VisitApp.Helpers;

namespace VisitApp.Views
{
    public partial class LoadingPage : ContentPage
    {
        public LoadingPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        protected override async void OnNavigatedTo(NavigatedToEventArgs args)
        {
                if (await IsAuthenticated())
                {
                    await HeaderUtil.AddUserInfoAsync();
                    await Shell.Current.GoToAsync($"///{nameof(MainPage)}");
                }
                else
                {
                    await Shell.Current.GoToAsync($"///{nameof(LoginPage)}");
                }
            //}
            base.OnNavigatedTo(args);
        }

        private static async Task<bool> IsAuthenticated()
        {
            return await Helpers.LoginData.IsAuthenticated();
        }

        protected override bool OnBackButtonPressed()
        {
            Application.Current.Quit();
            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you trying to navigate away from the *LoadingPage* as soon as it was navigated to? I don't understand what you're trying to do. When and how is the *LoadingPage* navigated to and when should the *LoginPage* be navigated to? You write that no error is thrown, but have you checked the debug output for warnings or messages?

Comment: @Julian `LoadingPage` is the first page defined in the AppShell, so it is the first page to be loaded when the app is run. In `OnNavigatedTo` I am checking if user is authenticated. If he is, a `GotoAsync` to `MainPage` is performed, otherwise, a `GotoAsync` to `LoginPage` is called to allow use to log in. That worked in .NET 7 but stopped working in .NET 8. What is the best way to accomplish what I need?

Comment: Please state these clarifications directly in your question and show more of the relevant code, please. Generally, you shouldn't perform navigation operations in the `OnNavigatedTo()` override as far as I can tell, because you're potentially starting a new navigation operation before the previous one has finished.

Comment: @Julian I have added more code to the question, but, if you tell that I should not perform navigation in `OnNavigatedTo` you forgot to clarify how I can do it.

Comment: @Julian In this page, programmer is doing the same as I do: https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/blogs/building-a-login-flow-with-net-maui

Comment: Yes, and that example probably stopped working with .NET 8.0 as well. I would recommend taking care of authentication in a service or at least handling it in *App.xaml.cs*. For example, you could set the `LoadingPage` in the constructor and then handle authentication and navigation in the `OnStart()` override.

Comment: @Julian I have moved the code inside `OnNavigatedTo` to `App.OnStart,  but it did not work either. I think it is because `LoadingPage` is actually navigated because it is the first page in `AppShell.xaml`. Can you explain how to set `LoadingPage` in constructor?

Comment: See this case: [How do you replace a page with another in MAUI?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77680467/how-do-you-replace-a-page-with-another-in-maui/77682733#77682733) ? I tested it on .NET8 and it works well.