# .NET Maui | OnAppearing Endless Popup

Tags: c#, .net, mvvm, maui

```
public partial class Login : ContentPage
{
    private readonly AuthenticateViewModel _authenticateViewModel;
    private readonly LoadingPopupManager _loadingPopupManager;

    public Login(AuthenticateViewModel authenticateViewModel, LoadingPopupManager loadingPopupManager)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        BindingContext = authenticateViewModel;
        authenticateViewModel.SetPage(this);

        _authenticateViewModel = authenticateViewModel;
        _loadingPopupManager = loadingPopupManager;
    }

    protected override void OnAppearing()
    {
        base.OnAppearing();
        _loadingPopupManager.ShowLoadingPopup(this);

        Task.Run(() =>
        {
            _authenticateViewModel.Initialize();

            Dispatcher.Dispatch(() =>
            {
                _loadingPopupManager.HideLoadingPopup();
            });
        });
    }

    protected override void OnSizeAllocated(double width, double height)
    {
        base.OnSizeAllocated(width, height);
        DeviceSizeManager.SetValues(height, width);
    }

    private void OnEyeTapped(object sender, TappedEventArgs e)
    {
        entry.IsPassword = !entry.IsPassword;
        icon.Text = entry.IsPassword ? MaterialCommunityIconsFont.EyeOutline : MaterialCommunityIconsFont.EyeOffOutline;
    }
}
```

```
public partial class Register : ContentPage
{
    private readonly AuthenticateViewModel _authenticateViewModel;
    private readonly LoadingPopupManager _loadingPopupManager;

    public Register(AuthenticateViewModel authenticateViewModel, LoadingPopupManager loadingPopupManager)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        BindingContext = authenticateViewModel;
        authenticateViewModel.SetPage(this);

        _authenticateViewModel = authenticateViewModel;
        _loadingPopupManager = loadingPopupManager;
    }

    protected override void OnAppearing()
    {
        base.OnAppearing();
        _loadingPopupManager.ShowLoadingPopup(this);

        Task.Run(() =>
        {
            _authenticateViewModel.Initialize();

            Dispatcher.Dispatch(() =>
            {
                _loadingPopupManager.HideLoadingPopup();
            });
        });

    }

    private void OnEyeTapped(object sender, TappedEventArgs e)
    {
        entryPassword.IsPassword = !entryPassword.IsPassword;
        passwordIcon.Text = entryPassword.IsPassword ? MaterialCommunityIconsFont.EyeOutline : MaterialCommunityIconsFont.EyeOffOutline;
    }

    private void OnEyeTappedRepeat(object sender, TappedEventArgs e)
    {
        entryRepeatPassword.IsPassword = !entryRepeatPassword.IsPassword;
        passwordRepeatIcon.Text = entryRepeatPassword.IsPassword ? MaterialCommunityIconsFont.EyeOutline : MaterialCommunityIconsFont.EyeOffOutline;
    }
}
```

```
 public class LoadingPopupManager
 {
     private SpinnerPopup spinnerPopup;

     public void ShowLoadingPopup(Page page)
     {
         spinnerPopup ??= new SpinnerPopup();
         page.ShowPopup(spinnerPopup);
     }

     public void HideLoadingPopup()
     {
         if (spinnerPopup == null)
             return;

         spinnerPopup.Close();
         spinnerPopup = null;
     }
 }
```

```
public ICommand GoToLogin => new Command(async async =>
{
    await Shell.Current.GoToAsync(nameof(Login), true);
});
```

On my login Page the Popup gets hidden when the ViewModel Initialize is done, however as soon as i land on my register page the popup never closes.

PopupManager is added as a singelton
Pages and ViewModels as transient

i am confused why the popup dissapears on the first page but after the "go to async" not anymore on the next page

Comment: If Login/Register is realized through Page(ContentPage) instead of Popup? See the solution of this case: [How do you replace a page with another in MAUI?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77680467/how-do-you-replace-a-page-with-another-in-maui/77682733#77682733).